# Error of mass assignement on my rspec test (Rails.32, active_admin, rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, activeadmin

I’m building a daily deal app to learn RoR.

My question is about `attr_accessible` and how to test a model where attributes are protected against mass-assignment.

I have 3 Models in my app:

- Users (through devise)
- Deals
- Admin_users (through active admin gem)

Basically Deals belongs_to Admin_users and I want only admin users sot be able to publish Deals.

The problem I have is that if I am not wrong, I needed to put all attributes `attr_accessible` so that I can create a form and save a Deal and then, to protect attributes (especially admin_user_id) I added `with_role` `as: :admin` to protect them and make only accessible to an admin (I used this as inspiration: http://ejholmes.github.io/2012/04/22/handling-mass-assignment-with-active-admin.html)

My problem is that RSpec tests that were working before putting `as: :admin`, are now failing and the error message I get is:

```
   ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
   Can't mass-assign protected attributes: url_path, country, title, description, twitter_msg, image_url, prelaunch_date, deal_launch_date, deal_end_date, featured, admin_user_id
```

I think RSpec does not get I am an admin so I have the right to mass assign theses attributes.

How can I solve this?

Here are my files for reference:

**deal_spec.rb**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :admin_user, :foreign_key => 'admin_user_id'

attr_accessible :url_path,
              :country,
              :title,
              :description,
              :twitter_msg,
              :image_url,
              :prelaunch_date,
              :deal_launch_date,
              :deal_end_date,
              :featured,
              :admin_user_id,
              :as => :admin_user

validates :title,
          presence: true,
          length: { maximum: 200 }
```

**My active admin set up: on initializers/active_admin.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

config.site_title = "My App"


config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path


config.batch_actions = true

# got it on http://ejholmes.github.io/2012/04/22/handling-mass-assignment-with-active-admin.html
module ActiveAdmin
 class BaseController
   with_role :admin_user
 end
end

end
```

- My tests files:

**The factory for admin_users:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_user do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}   
  password "admin_pass"
  password_confirmation "admin_pass"
end
end
```

**And the TEST that is actually failing: it's an example on the title lenght test:**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'date'

describe Deal do

let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }

before(:each) do
@attr = {
  url_path:    "lorem ipsum",
  country:     "France",
  title:       "lorem ipsum",
  description: "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum",
  twitter_msg: "http://www.example.com",
  image_url:   "http://www.example2.com",
  prelaunch_date:     2.days.from_now.change(hour: 10),
  deal_launch_date:   3.days.from_now.change(hour: 10),
  deal_end_date:      15.days.from_now.change(hour: 10),
  featured:           true,
  admin_user_id: 1
}

describe "tests TITLES" do
it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }

it "should reject title that is too long" do
  long = "a" * 211
  hash = @attr.merge(:title => long)
  Deal.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:title)
end


end
```

I feel I haven't told my deal_rspec.rb test file that :admin_user is really an admin! I don't know how to do it and even if I am protecting well my Deal model attributes against mass assignment. Does anybody know how I can make these tests pass again?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the :as => :admin flag is not referring to an active_record model, it's just an a arbitrary symbol your defining. Using it means you need to pass as: :admin in the create call like this

```
Deal.create(params[:deal], as: :admin)
```

So your actual problem is probably with your factory, since it doesn't know to pass the flag when it makes your object. Try something like this

```
factory :deal do
  my_attr "abc"
  initialize_with do
    create(attributes, as: :admin)
  end
end
```